# javascript ID selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, css-selectors

I have 2 forms

```
<form name= "form1" action="">
  <input type="hidden" name="max" id= "max1" value="100"/> 
  <input type="submit"  class="submit" value="part 1" />
</form>

<form name= "form2" action="">
  <input type="hidden" name="max2" id= "max2" value="200"/> 
  <input type="submit"  class="submit" value="part 2" />
</form>
```

I get the values from this form here

```
         $(".submit").click(function () {

 here  -->       var max_res = $("input#max1").val();
                 var  Results = "Max Result " + max_res;      
         });
```

My question is how can i dynamically change the id from **max1** to **max2** so I can store  **max2**'s value in **max-res** when a click is made in form2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var max_res = $('input[id^="max"]', $(this).parent()).val();
 //selects the id starting with max in this form
 var  Results = "Max Result " + max_res;
```

Comment: @princesden -- no problem ^_^ remember to select an accepted answer when you can (for this and your other questions)

Answer (score 1):

```
var i = 1;
var max_res = $("input#max"+i).val();
```

/edit: I would add common class to all inputs like class="max" and then:

```
var max_res = $(this).parent().find("input.max").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var max_res = $(this).closest("form").find("input:hidden").val()
```

Comment: ...who says there cannot be more than one hidden input?  -- then you are stuck!

Comment: This is true, I was just solving the current problem. If there was more than one hidden input you could put name or id attributes to identify them and change the .find selector to something like .find("input[name='foo']") or .find("#foo"). These would both work